# how to split dataframe with some sub-levels of certain columns and apply model in tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I use diamonds dataset as an example. I can split the dataset by cut and color, and then apply model and extract r-square as below.

```
diamonds %>% group_by(cut, color) %>% 
            do(model=lm(price~carat, data=.)) %>%
            mutate(r2 = summary(model)$adj.r.squared) %>% 
            select(-model)
```

The question is if I only want to group the data by some sub-levels in cut and color. For example:

```
cut_sub<- as.factor(c('Good','Fair'))
color_sub <- as.factor(c('E', 'J'))
```

How should I modify the codes above to achieve that? I tried and googled but could not find the solution.

Comment: Why not simply use `filter()` and keep only the relevant data ? Something like: `diamonds %>% filter(cut %in% c("Fair", "Good"), color %in% c("E", "J")) %>% group_by(cut, color) %>% ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea using `purrr` devel *`v0.2.2.9000`*

```
diamonds %>% 
  filter(cut %in% c("Fair", "Good"), 
         color %in% c("E", "J")) %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, .f = ~lm(price ~ carat, data = .)) %>% 
           map(summary) %>% map_dbl("adj.r.squared"))
```

Which gives:

```
## A tibble: 4 x 4
#    cut color               data     model
#  <ord> <ord>             <list>     <dbl>
#1  Good     E <tibble [933 x 8]> 0.8298957
#2  Good     J <tibble [307 x 8]> 0.9176254
#3  Fair     E <tibble [224 x 8]> 0.8092058
#4  Fair     J <tibble [119 x 8]> 0.7567011
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `purrr` way to do this:

```
diamonds %>% 
  filter(cut %in% c("Fair", "Good"), 
         color %in% c("E", "J")) %>% 
  slice_rows(c("cut", "color")) %>% 
  by_slice(function(.x) {
    lm(price~carat, data = .x) %>% 
      summary %>% 
      .$adj.r.squared
  }, .to = "r2") %>% 
  unnest(r2)
```

Comment: In the latest version of `purrr`, data-frame based mappers like `slice_rows` and `by_slice` have been moved to a new package called `purrrlyr`.